Proper syntax in redshift sql for "schema"."table"."field"?
I'm updating table_A with a variable, new_var, pulled in from table_B.
Both table_A and table_B are in the same schema.
alter table schema.table_A add column new_var varchar(3)

update schema.table_A
set schema.table_A.new_var = schema.table_B.new_var 
from schema.table_B where schema.table_A.record_id = schema.table_B.record_id

However, Redshift doesn't recognize the "schema"."table"."field" syntax format.
How do you identify variables from a specific schema and table?

Redshift does recognize the "schema"."table"."field" syntax format.
You don't have to specify the table and schema for schema.table_A.new_var
It is implied that the column you are updating (new_var) is a column of schema.table_A

Got it - this works:
UPDATE schema.table_A AS a
SET new_var = b.new_var
FROM schema.table_B AS b
WHERE a.record_id = b.record_id

You will have to use something like this if you are updating table_A from table_B in redshift.
update schema.table_A
set new_var = schema.table_B.new_var
from schema.table_B
where schema.table_A.record_id = schema.table_B.record_id

